# Spring - use annotational transaction management in command line tool

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-mvc, transactions

I am developing a small application in Java using Spring framework. As a part of it, I have developed a command line tool in this spring project that reads in a CSV file and inserts it in a MySQL database.

I would like to use Soring's own transaction management for the purpose and I find annotational method using `@Transactional` attractive. The problem is that the function with this annotation doesn't rollback even if exception is generated.

This is a small part of my code that I believe is relevant to this issue:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    //some variables and stuff here

    //getting application context
    ApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(BeanConfig.class);
    JdbcOperations jdbcOperations = applicationContext.getBean("jdbcOperations", JdbcOperations.class);
    UserDaoImpl userDaoImpl = applicationContext.getBean("userDao", UserDaoImpl.class);
    DBDaoImpl DBDaoImpl = applicationContext.getBean("dbDao", DBDaoImpl.class);

    UserDetailImporterTool importerTool = new UserDetailImporterTool(jdbcOperations, DBDaoImpl, userDaoImpl);

    //this functions calls a DAO 
    importerTool.execute(users, userFollowingMapCSV, batchSize);
}
```

This is the execute() function that is called form the above mentioned `main()`:

```
public int execute(List<User> users, String userFollowingMapCSV, int batchSize) throws Exception{
    // stuff here

    int numSuccessfulInsertions = userDaoImpl.insert(users, jdbcOperations, batchSize);

   // stuff here
}
```

This is the `insert()` function being called from `execute()` function stated above:

```
@Override
public int insert(@Nonnull List<User> user,
                  @Nonnull JdbcOperations jdbcOperations,
                  int batchSize) throws Exception
{
    //stuff here

        try {
            insertBatch(jdbcOperations,
                    userArgsList,
                    userDetailArgsList,
                    officialDetailArgsList,
                    residentialDetailArgsList
            );
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.warning("ERROR");
        }
    }
    // stuff here
}
```

And finally this is the `insertBatch()` function in DAO on which transaction management is applied on:

```
@Transactional("dataSourceTransactionManager")
private void insertBatch(JdbcOperations jdbcOperations,
                         List<Object[]> userArgsList,
                         List<Object[]> userDetailArgsList,
                         List<Object[]> officialDetailArgsList,
                         List<Object[]> residentialDetailArgsList
) throws Exception 
{
    try {
        jdbcOperations.batchUpdate(userSql, userArgsList);
        jdbcOperations.batchUpdate(userDetailSql, userDetailArgsList);
        jdbcOperations.batchUpdate(officialDetailSql, officialDetailArgsList);
        jdbcOperations.batchUpdate(residentailDetailSql, residentialDetailArgsList);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.warning(debugMessageIndicator + " Batch failed to insert. Error : " + e.getMessage());
        throw new Exception();
    }


}
```

And finally (I promise, this is the last snippet :P) this is my bean config file:

```
@EnableTransactionManagement
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class BeanConfig {

private static final String VALIDATION_QUERY = "SELECT 1";

@Autowired
private Environment env;

@Bean
public BasicDataSource dataSource() {
    String driverClassName = env.getProperty("db.driverClassName");
    String jdbcUrl = env.getProperty("db.jdbcUrl");
    String username = env.getProperty("db.username");
    String password = env.getProperty("db.password");

    BasicDataSource basicDataSource = new BasicDataSource();
    basicDataSource.setDriverClassName(driverClassName);
    basicDataSource.setUrl(jdbcUrl);
    basicDataSource.setUsername(username);
    basicDataSource.setPassword(password);

    basicDataSource.setValidationQuery(VALIDATION_QUERY);
    basicDataSource.setValidationQueryTimeout(1);
    basicDataSource.setTestOnBorrow(true);
    basicDataSource.setTestWhileIdle(true);

    return basicDataSource;
}

@Bean
public JdbcOperations jdbcOperations() {
    BasicDataSource dataSource = dataSource();
    return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
}

@Bean
public UserDAO userDao() {
    return new UserDaoImpl();
}

@Bean
public DBDao dbDao() {
    return new DBDaoImpl();
}

@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(){
    BasicDataSource dataSource = dataSource();
    return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource);
}
```

}

I believe all this was required to see complete flow of control. As you can see, even though I rethrow an exception, the rollback doesn't perform. I was told by someone that I cannot use annotational transaction management unless I deploy a WAR file of the project on Tomcat. Right now I run this from command line through maven.

Is this really the case that I cannot use `@Transactional` without deploying? Are there are any errors that are preventing a rollback form being performed?

I tried setting auto commit to false in `DataSource` bean but no success. Any pointers will be helpful.

Comment: using any annotation for this specific class --> UserDetailImporterTool  ?? this should be with-in the @Transactional scope. If not annotated this class please put @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class) in this class as well. Hope that works

Answer (score 0):

1. If I can see you have an checked exception. But in this case Spring
   Transaction  doesn't rollback a transaction by default. Only unchecked
   exceptions are rollbacked by default. Spring documentation says:

   > While the EJB default behavior is for the EJB container to
   >   automatically roll back the transaction on a system exception (usually
   >   a runtime exception), EJB CMT does not roll back the transaction
   >   automatically on an application exception (that is, a checked
   >   exception other than java.rmi.RemoteException). While the Spring
   >   default behavior for declarative transaction management follows EJB
   >   convention (roll back is automatic only on unchecked exceptions), it
   >   is often useful to customize this.

   You have to define it above your class:

   `@Transactional(rollbackFor=Exception.class)
   class YourClassName {}`

   Or you can specify your particular checked exception.
2. It is possible to use Spring Transaction(`@Transactional` and other annotations) without any servlet
   containers such as Tomcat. These are completely different things.

**UPDATE:** You also need to define transactionManager in your configuration class as shown [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/EnableTransactionManagement.html):

```
@Bean
     public PlatformTransactionManager txManager() {
         return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource());
     }
```

**UPDATE 2:** You do not need to load all the beans in your `main()` method  manually. Better way to specify the relationship between your beans. Only a main service should be loaded manually. And Spring container will do this job for you. Also transaction will work properly. As it shown [here](https://github.com/ipatsyan/TransactionRollbackExample.git).

Comment: I tried adding that right above declaration for class JdbcUserDao (the class containing all DB operations), but it didn't work. I also tried adding it on top of 'execute function but that didn't work too.'

Comment: Do you think you could provide a really small demo code for this? That would be helpful

Comment: I have created simple example of rollback in Spring Transaction. I hope this will help you. See UPDATE 2.

Comment: Thanks, this will be helpful. I will go through it and see what was wronng in my project.

Answer (score 0):

`UserDetailImporterTool` class should be with-in the `@Transactional` scope. If this class is not annotated please put following annotation above that class:

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
```

Comment: Should I be mentioning this in bean config or in the class source file?

Comment: where exactly you are getting the exception ?

Comment: I don't get any exceptions. Its just that the DB doesn't get rolled back on an exception.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm asking.. where are you getting or deliberately throwing the exception just to test the database roll-back ?

Comment: in `insertBatch()` function (the fourth code snippet), the batchUpdate() method generatedsa duplicate primary key exception, that I intentionally produce by duplicating a row in input CSV. I then rethrow a new `Exception`. Is the the correct way?